# septic pump trips new gfci on dedicated circut

Tags: gfci, pump, septic

Its 2/5/20118 now and my septic pump on a brand new gfci trips the gfci---the new float switch does not by itself trip the gfci--the pump by it self or in combo with the flooat switch does trip--I checked continuity black to ground no white to ground no black to white--YEA shows continuity--I find that curious!

I checked all 4 of my new gfci (o0nly one dedicated on a single circuit to the sump pump) and they are all working fine--except when I plug the pump in to the dedicated gfci on a single breaker/ciRcuit----any suggestions?

Comment: `I checked continuity` ... how did you check it?

Comment: The pump has a ground fault.  Its leaking electricity somewhere.

Comment: I thought it was recommended not to use a GFI for a sump pump, but I'm not sure.

Comment: GFCI are notorious for tripping on the surge of an electric motor.  Is the GFCI an outlet or a circuit breaker?